# What are outputs of remove_radius_outlier function in Open3D

Tags: python, 3d, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, open3d

I'm trying to clean up my point cloud by removing some off the outliers(noise if you will). For this im using the open3D function remove_radius_outlier. So if i first downsample my point cloud my code becomes:

```
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
voxel_down_pcd = pcd.voxel_down_sample(voxel_size=0.02)
cl, ind = voxel_down_pcd.remove_radius_outlier(nb_points= 1, radius=0.05)
```

Now my question is, what exactly are the outputs cl and ind? I'm guessing these are the outlying points. But how do I go from this function to a point cloud without the outlying points (so without noise).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As per the latest [Open3D documentation](http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/tutorial/Advanced/pointcloud_outlier_removal.html):

**cl:** The pointcloud as it was fed in to the model (for some reason, it seems a bit pointless to return this).

**ind:** The index of the points which are *not* outliers

You can turn this into your pointcloud without the outlying points using the following:

```
inlier_cloud = cl.select_by_index(ind)
```